# How to send ajax request in wordpress without displaying zero

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am trying to send ajax request to another php page in wordpress. But every time it returns zero with other results.I need to remove the zero. I tried die(); to remove the zero. But after calling this, whole screen becomes blank. My code is below,

Jquery,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function key_press(){
    jQuery.ajax({
url  : '<?php echo get_admin_url()?>admin-ajax.php',
type : 'POST',
data : jQuery('[name="ans_name"]').serialize()
}).done(function(result) {
// ta da
//alert("success");
jQuery("#widget_poll_id").html(result);

});
}

</script>
```

PHP,

```
  add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_'.$_POST['ans_name'], 'my_ajax' );
  add_action( 'wp_ajax_'.$_POST['ans_name'], 'my_ajax' );


  function my_ajax() {

    echo $_POST['ans_name'];

  die();

}
```

How could I get rid of from this situation ?

Comment: try removing the echo, and replace it with return?  delete die()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because your actions are not being called.

You need to declare the property `action` as below so that WP knows which action to call.

In your particular case you'll also have to declare `ans_name` (as opposed to `data`), so that `$_POST['ans_name']` exists. I'm guessing that you wish this AJAX request to be called on many occasions by the fact that you used `$_POST['ans_name']` in your hook name. If that is not the case, I suggest you use something static, as the hook could be called during other requests when you do not want it.

Finally, I've retrofitted your code with the WP AJAX handler, which will ensure all of the WP goodness that you may need during an AJAX request is included.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function key_press(){

        var data = {
            url:        '<?php echo get_admin_url()?>admin-ajax.php',
            type:       'POST',
            action:     jQuery('[name="ans_name"]').serialize(),
            ans_name:   jQuery('[name="ans_name"]').serialize()
        };

        var myRequest = jQuery.post(ajax_object.ajaxurl, data, function(response){
            alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);
        });

        myRequest.done(function(){
            alert("success");
        });

    }
</script>   

add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_'.$_POST['ans_name'], 'my_ajax' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_'.$_POST['ans_name'], 'my_ajax' );
function my_ajax(){

    echo $_POST['ans_name'];

    die();  // Required for a proper Wordpress AJAX result

}
```

**Addition**

To ensure AJAX requests for non-logged in users (the `nopriv` hook) are handeled correctly, add this to your `functions.php` file.

```
<?php
add_action('wp_head', 'plugin_set_ajax_url');
function plugin_set_ajax_url() {
?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var ajax_object = {};
        ajax_object.ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>';
    </script>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks it works. But I need little help. When I click on submit button it returns "ans_name=31". But I dont need "ans_name" I need only "31". I know its not too much difficult . But I could not find out that.

Comment: That's likely due to how you are getting the value for `ans_name` (and by proxy `action`) before making the AJAX request. I'm making an assumption about the type of field that `ans_name` is, but try replacing both instances of `jQuery('[name="ans_name"]').serialize()` with `jQuery('[name="ans_name"]').val()`.